# Convert delimited String to delimited Long as per String to Long mapping

Tags: java, string, java-8, csv

I have a string :

```
My name is amit
```

and a mapping :

```
My   -> 1121
name -> 1122
is   -> 1123
amit -> 1124
```

I want to get back :

```
1121 1122 1123 1124
```

where every word is mapped to its corresponding long value which is held in a HashMap.

Here is my version:

```
public String delimtedStringToLong(String input, String delimiter, Map<String, Long> map) {
        String[] arr = input.split(delimiter);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            sb.append(String.valueOf(map.get(arr[i])) + delimiter);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

I am doing this in Java 8. Can there be better approach for this. Thanks!

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Asking for "best approach" would be opinion based. Besides it hardly matters what way you use to do something as simple as this.

Comment: Updated my question. My bad, just got delayed there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd split the input string, stream it through a mapping function that takes the value from the map and then collect it back:

```
String input = "My name is amit";
Map<String, Long> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("My",   1121L);
map.put("name", 1122L);
map.put("is",   1123L);
map.put("amit", 1124L);

String output =
    Arrays.stream(input.split(" "))
          .map(s -> String.valueOf(map.get(s)))
          .collect(Collectors.joining());
```